Pandas: Convert rows in a single index datafram to columns in a multilevel index dataframe
I've the following dataframe:
    month name  product category  Metric       Flipkart         Active 
0      April      Accessories  Stock Quantity  NaN               1808.00
1      April      Accessories  Stock Quantity  0.0                   NaN
2      May        Accessories  Sales Quantity  NaN                 61.00
3      May        Accessories  Sales Quantity  0.0                   NaN
4      April           Anklet  Stock Quantity  NaN              21861.75

I'd like to convert it into this:

How do I achieve this? It has to be generic enough for when multiple rows need to be switched to columns. The column names to be switched will be available in a list.Doesn't necessarily have to be with pandas. I'm open to using other libraries as well.

IIUC, you can do .stack()/.unstack() to achieve the result:
df = (
    df.set_index(["month name", "product category", "Metric"])
    .stack()
    .unstack(level=[0, 3])
)
print(df)

Prints:
month name                          April             May         
                                   Active Flipkart Active Flipkart
product category Metric                                           
Accessories      Sales Quantity       NaN      NaN   61.0      0.0
                 Stock Quantity   1808.00      0.0    NaN      NaN
Anklet           Stock Quantity  21861.75      NaN    NaN      NaN


This almost works but has some of the month names repeated twice for some reason. Any idea why that might be?

@JudyTRaj Probably you have some whitespaces before/after the name. What is print(df["month name"].unique()) show you?

Just the 12 months
